# How to check if React Native Streetview successfully rendered a location

Tags: react-native, google-street-view

#### What am I using

I'm using [react-native-streetview](https://github.com/nesterapp/react-native-streetview) component on my mobile app.

#### What is my problem

Sometimes when I pass a location to the component it will render a Black Screen (probably because that point does not exist on StreetView).

#### What I need

I would like to know if there is a way to figure out wether the component successfully rendered a location or if it "rendered" a Black Screen.

Comment: The workaround that I found was to use an API call and check wether the position returns a valid Street View value or not, using this endpoint: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?key=YOUR_API_KEY&location=STRING_ADDRESS_OR_LAT_LNG_COORDINATES